# PHP - require_once unable to find files

Tags: php, vbulletin

So I'm using vbulletin and for about a week now all my mods have basically been broken. I think something is up with my php file pathing.

My code is as such:

```
<?php
// ####################### SET     PHP ENVIRONMENT     ###########################
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// #################### DEFINE IMPORTANT CONSTANTS #######################

define('THIS_SCRIPT', 'Roleplay-Chatroom');
define('CSRF_PROTECTION', true);
// change this depending on your filename

// ################### PRE-CACHE TEMPLATES AND DATA ######################
// get special phrase groups
$phrasegroups = array();

// get special data templates from the datastore
$specialtemplates = array();

// pre-cache templates used by all actions
$globaltemplates = array('chatroom',
```

);

```
// pre-cache templates used by specific actions
$actiontemplates = array();

// ######################### REQUIRE BACK-END ############################
// if your page is outside of your normal vb forums directory, you should change directories by uncommenting the next line
// chdir ('/path/to/your/forums');
require_once('../global.php');

// #######################################################################
```

// ########################  START MAIN SCRIPT ############################
// #######################################################################

```
$navbits = construct_navbits(array('' => 'RPGC Chatroom'));
$navbar = render_navbar_template($navbits);

// ###### YOUR CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE #####
$pagetitle = 'Roleplaying Chatroom';

// ###### NOW YOUR TEMPLATE IS BEING RENDERED ######

$templater = vB_Template::create('chatroom');
$templater->register_page_templates();
$templater->register('navbar', $navbar);
$templater->register('pagetitle', $pagetitle);
print_output($templater->render());

?>
```

And it outputs this error on the page:

Warning: require_once(/home/rpgchaz/public_html/chat/includes/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rpgchaz/public_html/includes/class_bootstrap.php on line 101

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/rpgchaz/public_html/chat/includes/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/rpgchaz/public_html/includes/class_bootstrap.php on line 101

Comment: Do said files exist?

Comment: Absolutely. In the exact areas where they are mentioned.

Comment: proper file permissions?

Comment: Where are you *requiring* `init.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Files have all permissions. init.php is being called by class_bootstrap.php which is being called by global.php

Comment: Seriously though.. does `init.php` exist in this *exact* path: `/home/rpgchaz/public_html/chat/includes/init.php`? Have you traced it?